# Energy-conservation for exothermic reactions

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, physical-chemistry

How do exothermic reactions not violate energy conservation if e.g reactants were given 2200kJ/mol of energy and product released 2300kJ/mol of energy, where has this +100kJ/mol come from?(2200kJ/mol to break bonds and 2300kJ/mol released from products bonds forming).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confused because you assumed the energy of the atoms in the reactants to be **zero** but this is not the case and thinking this is completely wrong since they have **[energy in the form of mass](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass%E2%80%93energy_equivalence)** , kinetic energy and other forms of energy too .

Let's say that the atoms in the reactant have energy $E$ (including their mass, kinetic energy etc.) . So , when you give some energy to the reactant (so that the atoms in the reactant separate), the atoms gain energy and their energy becomes

$E + bond \;dissociation\; energy \;of \;the\;reactant$ i.e $E + 2200$ for your case.

Now if the atoms are allowed to rearrange in a different pattern they release different amounts of energy and the energy they are releasing is coming from $E+2200$ . So , they can release $2300 J$ (or even more) of energy after rearranging and it doesn't violate the conservation of energy.

Most of the times it is noticed that the mass of the product is lesser than the mass of the constituent atoms and this is because the atoms released more energy than what they were supplied for rearranging.

Or it is possible that the kinetic energy of the atoms in the product is lesser than what they had when they were present as a constituent of the reactant.

Hope it helps ☺️.

Comment: Thank you this helps a lot

Comment: @110010110 glad to know this.